# Как сделать автоматическую отправку формы по кнопке через Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Мне нужен скрипт, который сканирует домены в файле domain.txt. После сканирования скрипт должен:

1. Открывать сервис safebrowsing (https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en);
2. В "URL" указать домен из файла domain.txt по порядку;
3. В "Additional details: (Optional)" скрипт должен указывать текст:

text text text text text

4. Далее скрипт должен ждать, пока пользователь пройдет вручную проверку reCAPTCHA (I'm not a robot) от Google и самостоятельно нажать кнопку "Submit report". После этого нас должно перенаправить на "https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/static/submit_success.html?hl=en" в случае, если нас перенаправило на адрес "https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/static/submit_success.html?hl=en" после нажатия кнопки "Submit report", то это означает, что репорт отправился успешно.

Теперь нам нужно снова открыть новую вкладку сервиса safebrowsing (https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en) и повторить то же самое для нового домена из списка domain.txt.

Вопрос: Как мне сделать так, чтобы после ручного ввода капчи пользователем скрипт автоматически нажимал кнопку "Submit report"? Я пробовал по ID, стилю, полной вставке кода, по чекбоксу зеленой галочки после ее решения, но ничего не помогает. В итоге я написал функцию time.sleep(15), которая ждет 15 секунд, чтобы пользователь успел ввести капчу. Это неправильно, скрипт должен сам нажимать кнопку "Submit report" после решения капчи пользователем.

```
import logging
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='[%(levelname)s] %(message)s')

def submit_report(driver, domain):
    # Открываем страницу для отправки отчета
    driver.get('https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en')

    # Вводим домен в поле "URL"
    url_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'url')
    url_field.clear()
    url_field.send_keys(domain)

    # Вводим текст в поле "Additional details: (Optional)"
    additional_details_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'dq')
    additional_details_text = '''text text text  text text text'''
    additional_details_field.clear()
    additional_details_field.send_keys(additional_details_text)

    # Ожидаем решения Google reCAPTCHA
    WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe[src^="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor"]')))

    # Ждем, пока пользователь решает капчу
    time.sleep(15)  # Приостановка выполнения программы на 25 секунд

    # Кликаем по кнопке "Submit Report" с помощью JavaScript
    submit_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[value="Submit Report"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit_button)

    # Ожидаем перехода на страницу успешной отправки отчета
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains('submit_success'))

        # Проверяем, был ли успешно отправлен отчет
        if 'submit_success' in driver.current_url:
            logging.info(f'Report for {domain} sent successfully')
            return True

    except TimeoutException:
        logging.warning(f'Timeout while waiting for report submission for {domain}.')

    return False

# Открываем файл с доменами
with open('domain.txt', 'r') as f:
    domains = f.read().splitlines()

# Опции для ChromeDriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

# Устанавливаем путь к ChromeDriver
service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Открываем браузер
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

try:
    index = 0  # Индекс текущего домена
    max_attempts = 3  # Максимальное количество попыток отправки отчета

    # Открываем файл successful.txt для записи
    with open('successful.txt', 'a') as successful_domains_file:

        while index < len(domains):
            domain = domains[index]
            attempts = 0  # Счетчик попыток отправки отчета

            while attempts < max_attempts:
                success = submit_report(driver, domain)

                if success:
                    # Записываем успешно отправленный домен в successful.txt
                    successful_domains_file.write(f'{domain} - успешно отправлен отчет ({time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")})\n')
                    break  # Успешно отправлено, переходим к следующему домену
                else:
                    attempts += 1
                    logging.warning(f'Retrying report submission for {domain} (attempt {attempts})...')

            if attempts >= max_attempts:
                logging.error(f'Failed to submit report for {domain} after {max_attempts} attempts.')

            index += 1  # Переходим к следующему домену

finally:
    # Закрываем браузер после работы скрипта
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)